# Alias For "Desktop And Screensaver" APP.?

Tags: screensaver

First time poster.
Glad I found this Forum; looks great.

Am a (very) Sr. Citizen now, so please bear with me a bit.

New iMac user. Sure is different than Windows.
Using High Sierra.

I would like to create a Desktop shortcut (for the Dock) that takes me directly to the Apple App that came already installed: The "Desktop and ScreenSaver" one.

So, I went to:/System/Library/CoreServices/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine.  as was suggested.

It shows the APP icon there, and that it is a Unix Executable which I guess is understandable.

a.  No matter where I go, or what I try, I cannot find any way to create an Alias to it. Under File, e.g., the Create An Alias is greyed out.
Nor does it come up after selecting the App in the window, and right-clicking.
Is there a way to make an Alias to it ?

b. I would like to see the Folders and Desktop & Screen Saver images apparently embedded in it.  Is there some way to ?

Much thanks,
Bob

Comment: I'm struggling to ascertain what you are actually trying to achieve. Firstly you don't want to create an Alias to the executable inside any package unless you have very specific requirements - It will not do what you expect. Secondly, the resources the Control Panel references are not contained within the package.